# @State variable to highlight items in a horizontal ScrollView menu

Tags: swiftui

I am practicing an app in which part of the menu is a horizontal scrollable list, a tiny circle should highlight the current selection. The code is below:

```
import SwiftUI
        
        struct ContentView: View {
            @State var index = 0
            
            var body: some View {
                
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators:false) {
                HStack(spacing: 30) {
                    
                ForEach(0..<topMenu.count, id: \.self){ menu in
                    TopMenu(menu: menu, index: $index)
                        }
                    }
            }
                }  
        }
        
       var topMenu = ["Shoes", "Clothing", "By Sports", "By Brand", "By Price"]
        
        struct TopMenu: View {
            var menu: Int
            @Binding var index: Int
            
            var body: some View {
                
                VStack(spacing: 8) {
                       Text(topMenu[menu])
                         .font(.system(size: 15))
                         .fontWeight(index == menu ? .bold : .none)
                         .foregroundColor(index == menu ? .black : .gray)
                     Circle()
                         .fill(Color.black)
                         .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                         .opacity(index == menu ? 1 : 0)
                 }
            }
        }
        
        struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
            static var previews: some View {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
```

But it all seems very static now and I can't seem figure out as to how do I change value of `@Binding` variable so that it shows current selection of items in `topMenu[]`?

[image: interim output for reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant to change selection on tap, that can be done as below

```
 VStack(spacing: 8) {
          Text(topMenu[menu])
             .font(.system(size: 15))
             .fontWeight(index == menu ? .bold : .none)
             .foregroundColor(index == menu ? .black : .gray)
             .onTapGesture {
                index = menu     // << here !!
            }
```